# Android Studio layout: match parent, wrap content and dp,

Tags: android-layout

I use a layout with dp dimensions for my project, but if I change device also the layout change.
So is there a way to do an universal layout?
What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a very broad question and there is a lot of material available on the web to address it. To get you started, the Android developer site has an excellent introduction to the topic of ["Supporting Multiple Screens"](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html). I think that this is what you are looking for.

> **Supporting Multiple Screens**
>
> Android runs on a variety of devices that offer different screen sizes and densities. For applications, the Android system provides a consistent development environment across devices and handles most of the work to adjust each application's user interface to the screen on which it is displayed. At the same time, the system provides APIs that allow you to control your application's UI for specific screen sizes and densities, in order to optimize your UI design for different screen configurations. For example, you might want a UI for tablets that's different from the UI for handsets.